# How to start Alarm Manager on Device Reboot

Tags: android

I've have a simple app to schedule a notification 5 minutes after a button is pressed. It works fine for me. But if I restart the phone within that 5 minutes I don't get the notification. I have done a research on Alarm Manager and Scheduling Notifications on device reboots. I have a basic idea but I really don't know how to implement it into my project. I have 4 classes in my project.   They are:

- MainActivity
- NotificationUtil
- NotificationPublisher
- NotificationView

This is the my NotificationUtil class:

```
public class NotificationUtil
{
    public static void createNotification(Context context,Class<?> cls, String title, String content)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context,cls);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);

        sendNotification(getNotification(pendingIntent,context,title,content),context);
    }

    private static void sendNotification(Notification notification,Context context)
    {
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, NotificationPublisher.class);
        notificationIntent.putExtra(NotificationPublisher.NOTIFICATION_ID,1);
        notificationIntent.putExtra(NotificationPublisher.NOTIFICATION,notification);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,0,notificationIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 5*60 * 1000,pendingIntent);
    }

    private static Notification getNotification(PendingIntent pendingIntent, Context context, String title, String content)
    {
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context,"ChannelID");
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_bell);
        builder.setContentTitle(title);
        builder.setContentText("You have a Notification");
        builder.setSubText("Tap To View");
        builder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(content));
        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        return builder.build();
    }
}
```

This is my NotificationPublisher class:

```
public class NotificationPublisher extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static String NOTIFICATION_ID = "notification_id";
    public static String NOTIFICATION = "notification";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Notification notification = intent.getParcelableExtra(NOTIFICATION);
        int notificationId = intent.getIntExtra(NOTIFICATION_ID, 1);
        notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notification);
    }
}
```

This is how I call the NotificationUtil class on button click in the MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button button;
    private Context context;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = findViewById(R.id.notification);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                NotificationUtil.createNotification(MainActivity.this,NotificationView.class,"Notification","You have a new Task");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.notificationtest">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".NotificationView"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"/>

        <receiver android:name=".NotificationPublisher">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <receiver android:name=".DeviceBootReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

I have created a new DeviceBootReceiver class:

```
public class DeviceBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        if(intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"))
        {

        }

    }
}
```

But I'm not sure what to put in the onReceive function. I tried putting this in the onReceive function

```
 Intent pushIntent = new Intent(context, NotificationPublisher.class);
            context.startService(pushIntent);
```

Works normal, but if I reboot my phone, after 5 minutes I get a message "The Application has stopped working"

I have a basic idea after having gone through these tutorials but I don't know how to implement them into my project

https://www.stacktips.com/tutorials/android/repeat-alarm-example-in-android
https://droidmentor.com/schedule-notifications-using-alarmmanager/

What I need is, to get the notification even after my phone is rebooted. If any one out there who could help me to achieve this, I would be grateful.

Comment: hey @SaifThaha any of these answers solved your problem?

Comment: Hey@ Zafer Celaloglu Sorry for the late reply. None of them solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a `BroadcastReceiver` in order to be able to listen REBOOT event that is delivered by OS and then you can start your alarm manager there again

Comment: Can you please show me an example of how to implement it to my project if you don't mind?

Comment: like your NotificationPublisher, you just need to define it in AndroidManifest along with action(android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED) and then you can listen reboot action in onReceive() method in your BroadcastReceiver, just look at another answer :)

Comment: http://www.jjoe64.com/2011/06/autostart-service-on-device-boot.html

For example like that :) but in onReceive setup alarm again

Answer (score 0):

Well here is a complete example of an AutoStart Application.

Give permission of RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED in manifest file, and register your broadcast for BOOT_COMPLETED.

**AndroidManifest file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="pack.saltriver" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">

        <receiver android:name=".autostart">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity android:name=".hello"></activity>
        <service android:enabled="true" android:name=".service" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**autostart.java**

```
public class autostart extends BroadcastReceiver 
{
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) 
    {
        // This callback will be fired automatically when device starts after boot
        // Do your alarm alarm manager work here
    }
}
```